# Список алгоритмов на C#

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Недавно набрел на сайт "Список алгоритмов и структур данных на Java" например вот описан [алгоритм имитации отжига](http://sites.google.com/site/indy256/algo/simulated_annealing) . В общем показалось это очень удобно, может кто видел такое же для C#? Сложно ли будет на крайний случай сконвертировать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для таких задач - абсолютно не сложно. [JLCA](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=14349) 80% работы сделает, визуализационную часть придётся ручками доработать.

Как пример - [Mp3Sharp](http://robburke.net/mle/mp3sharp/), декодер mp3, он конвертирован из явы.